# Mapping Array into Angular Material Tree - Angular 9

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material, treeview, angular-material2

I am trying to map array structure to generate tree structure using `Material Tree Library - MatTreeFlatDataSource`.

I am having trouble with `buildFileTree()` method to return correct node to render the output as expected.

I need to maintain `id` within the `tree/json` structure so I can easily track (eventually save in database) when new item is added to the JSON object.

Array/Json structure:

```
const TREE_DATA = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    item: 'section-a',
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        item: 'sub-section-a'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item: 'section-b',
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        item: 'sub-section-b'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        item: 'sub-section-b2',
        children: [{
          id: 6,
          item: 'sub-subsection-b2'
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Expected Output:

```
 - section-a
     - sub-section-a
 - section-b
     - sub-section-b
     - sub-section-b2
         - sub-subsection-b2
```

and so on ...

sample link: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxgeqn

Project detail:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.2
@angular/cdk                      9.0.0
@angular/cli                      9.0.2
@angular/material                 9.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.2
@schematics/angular               9.0.2
@schematics/update                0.900.2
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

Any feedback/solution is appreciated.